# Trying to save file in Android, SDCard not installed or path is incorrect in Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb

I am Android Newbie dev, so forgive me if i am asking anything very easy.
I created a file saver in Android and it saves file to certail location, but when it tries to save, it says Access denied, may be in emulator the sdcard is not correctly made and it is not finding any such location to save file or there is some thing wrong with location of sdcard, the path which is showing in it is not the right path, and there can be a case that there is no sdcard in emulator installed, because when i open the camera it says, Please insert SD Card, if this is the problem then tell me an easy way to successfully create an SDCard, i tried to make it using adb shell, but its not working, anyway i am attaching an image file which can explain the situation very well.[image]

Comment: did you set the right permissions? also, how are you getting the address of your sd card directory?

Comment: Can you put the relevant code so that we can take a look?

Comment: from where i can set permission?

Answer (score 0):

Add this Permission as well same as you can see in below snap:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image: Manifiest.xml]

Comment: in which file and where to write this?

Comment: Open the Manifiest.xml file and add permissions,as above you can see :-)

Answer (score 0):

When creating avd do the following. Window--> Avd Manager -->New --> Give name and target. In SD card size give 500 MB or whatever size you want. Click Create. Now run your application on this avd and check.